# Excel export last row to pdf

Tags: excel, vba

```
ID          Employee    Date       Base 
1234        me          11/03/2015  UK 
9999        U           11/03/2015  UK  
1111        Us          11/03/2015  UK
```

Hi I have the above sample table that is updated each time a user saves data from a user form. I need to be able to export the most recent row to a PDF. I have written the following code but I am only getting data in the last row of column A. How can I get the whole row to be exported?

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler


'Make Sheet2 active
Sheet2.Activate

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file

' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(ws.Name, " ", ""), ".", "_") _
        & "_" _
        & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm") _
        & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=strFile, _
    FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
    Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
 ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=myFile, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

MsgBox "PDF file has been created."
End If

exitHandler:
Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
Resume exitHandler

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to export the filled part of the last row as **PDF**

```
Sub PDFMaker()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, M As Long, N As Long
    Dim myFile As String
    myFile = "qwerty"
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    N = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    M = ws.Cells(N, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(N, 1), ws.Cells(N, M)).ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Taking this one step further - is it possible to apply similar code to a user form so that when a user clicks an 'export' button they can create the pdf in the same format as the form?

Comment: @user2315491 Because Excel has a built-in ability to export *Cells*, I would have the button code transfer the UserForm data to a block of cells and then perform the export from those cells.